# Change confirmation text for Wordpress Newsletter Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, newsletter

I wanna change the confirmation text for newsletter subscription. I had Newsletter plugin installed on my Wordpress site. The location for confirmation text was at newsletter/subscriptions/page.php.

```
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
```

Can you please tell me where can I edit that message text?

---

> Ex. "You have successfully subscribed to the newsletter. You'll
>   receive a confirmation email in few minutes. Please follow the link in
>   it to confirm your subscription. If the email takes more than 15
>   minutes to appear in your mailbox, please check your spam folder."
>   (that was the default text)

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress each plugin is located in ~/www/wp-content/plugins/
There you select the plugin that you would like to change and find the part of code you want.
I don't know if this is the best way but that's the way I've been doing it

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I found what you said but I installed another plugin for easier configuration